# window.onload in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have this the javascript work perfectly in chrome but not work on IE7:

The click of id icsave , not work. Nothing happens, icsave save the page normaly

```
window.onload = function() {
    if ($('#MODE').val() != 'U') {
        $('#MOD_BY_JS').val( % 1);
        clik('#ICSave')
    }
};

function clik(element) {
    try {
        document.getElementById(element).click();
    }
    catch (e) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        var cb = document.getElementById(element);
        cb.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
};​
```

Comment: It would help if you are more specific about what does not work. What are you expecting to see, what did you see instead, and what have you done to try to troubleshoot th problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.onload` may not get executed for a number of reasons.

- Some resource on the page isn't loaded (images), since `window.onload` only fires after all resources have loaded.
- Something is overwriting `window.onload`
- You have a javascript error somewhere else

My suggestion to you is that since you're using jQuery, use either:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /* initialize stuff */});
```

or if you actually need `onload`

```
$(window).load(function(){ /* initialize stuff */});
```

For your example I would recommend using the `$(document).ready(...)` method as it looks to me your script will work as soon as the dom is ready, which is when the `ready` event fires.

Comment: if you don't have make a possibility to make save , create a function with setTimeout. Ex function Save(){setTimeout('Save Function',1)}